# Valen la pena los Getters y Setters ?? Java, buenas prácticas

Tags: java, buenas-prácticas

Soy relativamente nuevo en java (y en la programación) y me surgió una duda;
Los Getters y Setters son una de las cosas mas nombradas en lo que a buenas prácticas se refiere, sin embargo, programando me surgió una clase de 600 líneas de código en donde 300 son solamente Getters y Setters (literalmente). Mi pregunta es: hasta que punto es óptimo el uso de Getters y Setters ??
No solo que llevan tiempo y código extra, sino que hacen el todo el código confuso. En ocasiones, por ejemplo, he tenido que crear diferentes Setters, o Getters, para el mismo objeto, especialmente con las interfaces gráficas; por ej. un JLabel con Setter para cambiar el color, y otro para cambiar el texto.
En fin, quería saber que opinaban, son realmente necesarios ??

Comment: Me preocupa que tengas 150 variables en una clase ...

Answer (score 3):

> Encapsulamiento:Es la propiedad que permite asegurar que la información de un objeto está oculta del mundo exterior.
>   El encapsulamiento consiste en agrupar en una Clase las características(atributos) con un acceso privado y los comportamientos (métodos(getters y setters)) con un acceso público.
>   Acceder o modificar los miembros de una clase a través de sus métodos. Si puediera acceder directamente a los atributos podria pasar por ejemplo algo asi:

```
 public class Persona{
 public String nombre;
 pueblic int edad;
 }
```

> Uso la clase desde el main

```
Persona ej1 = new Persona();
edad=-329;
```

> Como se ve en el ejemplo no hay ningun contro de acceso en la clase ejemplo. Eso por un lado, supongamos que deceo usar la clase Persona para otros proyectos. Y despues de analizarlo decido que es mejor para la clase que el atributo edad sea una tomada como una fecha de naciemiento. Deberia cambiar todas las clases donde utilice la clase persona.

Una clase debe ser programada como una caja negra. El cliente de mi clase debe saber lo que hace la misma pero no, como lo hace, la forma correcta de modelar la clase Persona, seria.

```
public class Persona{
  //aca podes poner protected tambien por temas de herencia, private impide que lo 
  //pueda recolectar directamente desde afuera
  private String nombre;
  private int edad;
  //en el constructor inicializo los atributos
  public Persona(String nombre, int edad){
    //aca se puede validar la edad verificando que sea mayor que 0
    this.nombre=nombre;
    if(edad>0)
      this.edad=edad;
    else
       System.out.println("error");
  }
  //getters y setters
  public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
  }
  public void setNombre(String nombre){
  this.nombre=nombre;
  }
  public int getEdad(){
   //si cambiara el atributo int edad por FechaNavimento edad; solo tendria 
   //que realizar el calculo en este metodo y devolverlo, entonces las demas clases
   //ni se enteran del cambio. 
   return edad;
  }
  public void setEdad(int edad){
    if(edad>0)
      this.edad=edad;
    else
      System.out.println("error");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Son buenas practicas, tan  asi que son un estándar por ejemplo tecnologías como firebase , la librería Gson en android exigen que sigas este estándar para enviar tus objetos a la base de datos o deserializarlos . alli te dejo una imagen de una de mis clases de un proyecto en el que trabajo, mas o menos asi queda una clase , ademas no se debe acceder en ningun momento a una variable desde fuera de su clase directamente , siempre se debe hacer uso de greter and setter , la mayoria de los IDEs para java permiten que con las teclas alt+insert puedas generar greters and setters automaticamente , es decir el IDE lo hace por ti

imagen tomada de https://www.dokry.com/378

[image: tomado de https://www.dokry.com/378]

[image: parte de mi codigo]